# Name for a disk that bisects a ball

Tags: geometry, terminology

In two dimensions, a disk is bisected by lines through its center. These lines are called "diameters". In three dimensions *diameters* still refer to one dimensional lines through the center of the ball. Is there a widespread term for the bisecting *planes* (or maybe I should write disks, as they are cropped) of a ball?

Thank you!

Comment: In two dimensions, lines through the center of a circle are called "diameters". Never heard of "equators". For a sphere, its intersection with a plane through the center is called "[great circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_circle)"

Comment: @Aretino Right, I don’t know why I got it wrong here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be an established term, but **equatorial disk** could be said to carry the authority of William P. Thurston, based on this page from [Three-Dimensional Geometry and Topology](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Three_dimensional_Geometry_and_Topology.html?id=9kkuP3lsEFQC&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y) (1997):

[image]

Comment: The drawback of this term is that it seems to presuppose an "orientation" (in some sense) of the ball in question. One doesn't tend to think of a ball or sphere as having many different "equators", only one.

Answer (score 2):

According to the definition given in the Wikipeadi article [Bisection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection), bisection refers to "the division of something into two equal or congruent parts". So given a 3D object like a sphere, if you want to divide it in two parts of equal volume, you do it using a plane. Naturally, such a plane is bisecting the sphere.